Chromadb not able to write SQLite database in Azure file system
I created an application using Chainlit, LangChain and Chromadb deployed on Azure Container Apps. I created persistent storage using Azure storage account and mounted on Azure Container Apps. The container is able to write to the shared storage but the application is not able to write to the SQLite database in the storage.
The code is stuck here:
# Create a Chroma vector store
db = await cl.make_async(Chroma.from_texts)(
   all_texts, embeddings, metadatas=metadatas, persist_directory = chroma_persistent_directory
   ,collection_name = 'tmp1')
logger.info("finished with db")

The created SQLite database file is zero bytes. There are no permission or network problems (I am able to create the file and there are no specific user permissions for the application).


I had a similar issue with sqllite in an Azure Container App. For me it was fixed when I added nobrl to the mounting options.

you need to configure the mountOptions:
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=1000
    - gid=1000
    - mfsymlinks 
    - nobrl 
    - cache=none


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
